# Hardware back button invoke background running android app

Tags: android, button, background, back-button

I am having below scenario:

My app ->Launch the browser->by clicking link on browser its Launch the another app (Which not in my control).

Our requirement is when user hit back from last launch application it should get back to my application which is running in background.

is there any possibility using service or some receiver that will take back button event when app is in background?

Comment: You'd need to alter the application stack as it is `your app -> browser -> new app`, the back button would return to the previous app, which is the browser. If this is at all possible, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of launching the Browser, you can use web view to display the HTML page. Then your app would be below the third party app in the application stack. So when user presses the back button, your app would come in the foreground.